# How can you align multiple table rows against a single table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm not exactly sure how do this, or if it is even possible. If it isn't, could you please provide an alternative?

Here's a screenshot of a table in Word I made, to show what I mean:

[image]

I want to recreate the same thing with html tables, however I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">One row</td>
            <td>These</td>
            <td>are</td>
            <td>multiple</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>rows</td>
            <td>against</td>
            <td>one</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table, td {
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">One row</td>
  <td>these</td>
  <td>are</td>
  <td>multiple</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>rows </td>
  <td>against</td>
  <td>one</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```